# Adding a css file reference in Sharepoint online Master page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I m using Sharepoint online, now I want to add a css file reference in Masterpage.

I have used following code in Oslo and seattle.HTML files, but I m getting an error 

error- SharePoint requires HTML files to be XML-compliant. Your file isn't XML-compliant, likely because of tag properties without quotes, missing closing tags, or invalid properties in tags.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint master page, the custom CSS style needs to load after the main SharePoint styling CSS file "corev4.css" gets loaded.

Check if the reference convert to below inside the masterpage .master file or not:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Styles/test.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="corev15.css" />
```